# NHibernate load the nested complex object entity in automapper queryable extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, automapper

I am having class employee which contain complex property Department.

```
public Class Employee
{ 
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public Department {get; set;} 
}
public Class Department 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name { get;set;}
}
```

i create the map for both
(consider the above both class are available in two namespace 'source', 'destination')

```
Mapper.CreateMap<source.Employee,destination.Employee>()
Mapper.CreateMap<source.Department,destination.Department>()
```

when i project it.

```
empQueryable.Project().To<destination.Employee>();
```

If i saw the NHProfiler
I found that it loads the entity Department
and create the query

```
select ... from employee left outer join Department .....
```

i don't know why it loads entity Department, it should make just the projection.

Comment: Can you show the mappings? Is the `Department` property eager loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that "destination.Employee" contains references to the "destination.Department". When AutoMapper builds a projection, it does the same as it would as "Mapper.Map". It crawls the destination type, its properties, and its member's properties all the way down. In short, it will build a Select expression something like:

```
.Select(e => new destination.Employee {
    Id = e.Id,
    Department = new destination.Department {
        Id = e.Department.Id,
        Name = e.Department.Name
    }
});
```

You have a few choices here:

1. Ignore members you don't want mapped in your employee configuration, namely the "Department" property
2. Create targeted destination types based on use case, and don't share destination types that require different hydrated data based on different needs.
3. Use explicit expansion (ForMember(d => d.Department, opt => opt.ExplicitExpansion()), then explicitly expand that member in your projection as needed, with the overload for "Project.To" that takes a list of members to expand.

Comment: Why don't it happen in case of one to many mapping. It happen only in one to one and many to one case. Can you have any sample app which override to Project.To. I tried to write it but didn't complete it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably because you didn't flatten with the collections. It still happens, AutoMapper supports lists and collections in projections. All that I'm doing in projections is taking what you *would* have done in Mapper.Map and create a LINQ Select expression. The AutoMapper wiki and tests have documentation and samples.